# Conflicting constrains with Un-deletable system set constrain

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to add a height constraint to a label so that it doesn't cut off the text that is inside:

[image]

However, when I added the height constrain to the label, a conflicting constrain error shows up prompting me to delete one of the constrains, if I just leave this message unsolved, the UI works correctly:

[image]

But what confuses me in the error is the fact that the constrain which I had just added seems to be conflicting with an un-deletable constrain height = 0 and I have no idea where is is coming from (The height = 250 is for the stack view):

[image]

I could make the error message go away by setting the priority of the label's height constrain lower than 1000, but doing this brings the 'label too small cutting off text' problem right back:

[image]

What could be causing this? What I am confused about is:

- What is causing the height = 0 un-deletable constrain?
- Why is that if I leave this error message unfixed, the UI works as intended?

Thank You for any help!

Comment: What settings do you have on the stackview?  Have you tried increasing the label's vertical compression resistance rather than setting a height?

Comment: Thank for the help, I have explained the solution in detail in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tips from Paulw11 for the solution:

I solved the problem by adjusting the label's vertical compression resistance rather than setting a height. I removed the height constrain which removed the error message. In the settings for the stackview, there is a field for "Vertical Content Compression Resistance Priority" (Set to 750 here):

[image]

The problem was fixed when the "Vertical Content Compression Resistance Priority" of the label itself was set to a value higher than than that of the stackview's (Set to 1000 here):

[image]